# How many permutations of $n$ elements are there which move $k$ elements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many permutations of the elements $[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ are there which actually move $k\leq n$ elements and keep $n-k$ elements at the same position? 
What I mean by *move* is that, if element $x_i$ is moving, then the corresponding permutation matrix has a 0 at entry $(i,i)$.

Is there a closed formula for that?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers.

Comment: Close to closed. The $n-k$ elements can be chosen in $\binom{n}{n-k}$ ways. Now we need to count the number of **derangements** of $k$ elements, please see Wikipedia for that.  You can also search for the word on MSE.